# Are small clay capacitors pose any health hazards?

Tags: capacitor, resistors, safety

I'm making a small activity with children where we will be using capacitors and resistors to make jewellery like earrings. Do they contain any materials that pose a skin or otherwise health hazard?

Comment: Are they used? Only skin hazard I could see is if they're recycled parts they could have traces of lead solder on them still.

Comment: Most components are RoHS (Restriction of the use of certain Hazardous Substances) compliant **BUT** as you are asking about a non-standard use of the components (i.e. potential allergy) this puts it into a different framework and you may need to get medical advice. All I can say is that I have used these components for over over 50 years and have had no problems.

Answer (score 1):

I think the real hazards are not from the substances these parts are made from contacting skin, but:

Swallowing.  These parts are not designed to the small part size quidelines for children that toys must adhere to, and I'm sure many are too small.

Pricking the skin.  Some parts are sharp and strong enough to puncture the skin if done with enough imagination.

Heavy metal ingestion.  I don't think that the metals in these parts pose much credible risk to skin exposure, but licking them or otherwise ingesting liquid, particularly acids (like most juices), that have come in contact with the parts may not be safe.

Burns.  The parts themselves wouldn't burn anyone, but if you are going to solder them to assemble this jewelry, then there will be high temperatures involved.  Soldering iron burns are small and would generally pose no long-term danger, but they can hurt quite a bit for hours to a day.

Poking eyes.  Lots of small pointy things together with a number of small children doesn't sound like a good mix.

How serious these threats are depends on how young the children are, how many of them, and how well supervised.  Since you haven't told us any of that, you'll have to judge the severity of these risks yourself.

Comment: I think there is some risk of chronic skin contact with the metals involved. For example, I would definitely not recommend putting a tin-plated component lead through any kind of piercing.

Comment: Re: pricking the skin, I was walking around in my stocking feet and stepped on a 8 pin DIP lying upside down on the floor.  Ouch!

Comment: @GeorgeHerold the modern-day version of caltrops...